# Ubuntu Lenovo bcm43162 WiFi Driver

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I want to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo z51 Laptop.
It has a Broadcomm bcm43162 Wifi Card.

When I boot into the Live CD, it doesnt have WiFi.
When I go into the terminal and try:

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

It installs succesfully, but I still dont have a network connection.

A year ago I've managed to get it to work on my Ubuntu partition, but it got corrupted and I've forgotton how I did that.

I've tried Linux Mint, Manjaro & Ubuntu but they all don't seem to work.

Edit: Someone suggested: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

But I've already stated that when I try

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

Nothing happens. And I can't reboot since I used the Live CD, because I want it to work first before I format my main partition.

Comment: When you check your device with lspci -nn, does it sat that firmware-b43-installer is correct for your device?

Comment: It cant even find it.
E: Unable to locate package: firmware-b43-installer.

Comment: According to `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`, and next referring to the duplicate, what is the correct driver for your device? I strongly suspect that it is *NOT* firmware-b43-installer.

Comment: Then what is? b43 firmware is the only thing that pops up if you search for my WiFi card on Google.

Comment: Again, what does `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` report??

Comment: This is what Terminal says: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ae] (rev 02)

Comment: I've searched the internet some more in the past few days but couldnt find anything. Is there literally nothing?

Comment: please read this answer it has your solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: No Linux driver for this card exists yet: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:14e4-43ae-17aa-0622

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt install net-tools
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

It work for me

Comment: What is the ID of your card? The [14e4:43ae]  is not supported by kernel or wl yet.